# Datatables: Browser freezes after ajax has been load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

**Problem: Browser freezes after Ajax data is loaded and shown**

I have performance issues using Datatables, im using ajax / server-side processing but ran into some very serious performance troubles.

Above a certain amount of rows that are loaded (50+) the rows appear in the table but after 2-3 seconds  the Browser Tab freezes (nothing clickable, no tooltips..) according to the amount of rows for some seconds. 1000+ rows creates a permanent freeze, the tab has to be closed and the page reloaded.

Anyone experienced such a behavior in the past? Its like the rows are processed and after everything is ready the browser suddenly freezes for some seconds.

**Backend:**
Debian 10
Laravel 5.8 (+yajra/laravel-datatables)

**Browser:** Chrome 77 (Problem also occurring in current Firefox release)

**My Datatable Config:**

```
    var table = $('#tblCashflow').DataTable({
    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    searching: true,
    bfilter: false,
    paging: true,
    bLengthChange: false, //dropdown show x entries
    info: true,
    searchDelay: 3000,
    ajax: {
        url:$('#routeCashflowTable').val(),
        method:'post'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'client_name',  name: 'client_name',   orderable: false,   searchable: true   },
        { data: 'study_name',   name: 'study_name',    orderable: false,   searchable: false  },
        { data: 'product_name', name: 'product_name',  orderable: false,   searchable: true   },
        { data: 'body_area',    name: 'body_area',     orderable: false,   searchable: false  },
        { data: 'date_time',    name: 'date_time',     orderable: false,   searchable: false  },
        { data: 'price',        name: 'price',         orderable: false,   searchable: false  },
        { data: 'client_id',    name: 'client_id',     orderable: false,   searchable: true, visible: false   },
    ],

    "language": {
        "url": "/custom/datatables/dataTables.german.lang"
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet on some javascript processing. Turn on profiler in browser and watch what eats CPU. It may be "trivial" computed value recalculating over and over…
Profiler will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

It was the storage behaviour of the Laravel-Debugbar causing the freezes.
The storage can be disabled unter

**config/debugbar.php**

```
    'storage' => [
    **'enabled'    => true,**
    'driver'     => 'file', 
    'path'       => storage_path('debugbar'), 
    'connection' => null,   
    'provider'   => '' 
],
```

Set "enabled" to false and the performance issues are gone but there may be errors in the console if the displayed valus are too long for the http headers.